# Can similarity detection techniques be applied to a text document formatted as a big ASCII encoded integer byte array?

Tags: machine-learning, cosine-similarity

I would like to detect similarities between files. One way of doing this is to encode the file in order to reduce the input space to the similarity algorithm and second to have more accurate results for the result. This is done by taking into account only informative features of the document. One way of doing this is to transform the file into a vector space transformation following the tf-idf frequence which scales up terms that are very informative and scales down frequent terms. My question is whether this can be done in a document where its text representation is not preserved. Suppose for instance that first the document is transformed into a big integer array where its character is represented as its ASCII value.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Characters are always represented with some numeric value, be it ASCII or UNICODE. How is your approach different from the standard one? Also I don't think that it is necessary to use tf-idf to encode text as a vector, e.g. bloom filter can be used as is.

Comment: @IvanKoblik if you make dictionary (word ID) and then apply bloom filter it is a basic version of tf-idf (word is presented, or not)

Comment: bloom filter???Bloom filter is a probabilistic data structure. I am talking about encoding issues. I mean in some python libraries as scikit learn the files are treated based on words. First there is an index vocabulary construction and then there is a term frequency phase.I don't want that. I would like to be treated as a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @curious  what does "text representation is not preserved" mean? (e.g. word order)?

Comment: @xhudik am treating the text as a stream of bytes. The input to the similarity detection algo is not text with words but numerical values.So there is no way to determine words frequency or it is?I don't want the basic unit block to be the word but a stream of bytes.

Comment: @xhudik You're right I thought of tf-idf in the more complete form where you take into account term frequency in the corpus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The encoding of your document in byte array is not a problem as @Ivan Koblik pointed out since texts are always encoded with numeric data.  Your task is a standard document similarity detection problem. I suggest the below steps:

## Pre-processing

- decoding
- tokenization;
- case folding;
- removing stop words;
- stemming.

## Generating features

- as you pointed out, tf-idf might be a good one.
- a set of weighted features constitutes a high-dimensional vector.

## Fingerprinting

Using `simhash` or [locality-sensitive-hash](/questions/tagged/locality-sensitive-hash), you can transform the high-dimensional vector into an `f-bit` fingerprint, e.g., `f=64`. This is exactly the technique used by Google for [near duplicate web page detection](http://www.wwwconference.org/www2007/papers/paper215.pdf).

> We maintain an
> f-dimensional vector V , each of whose dimensions is initialized to zero. A feature is hashed into an f-bit hash value. These f bits (unique to the feature) increment/decrement
> the f components of the vector by the weight of that feature
> as follows: if the i-th bit of the hash value is 1, the i-th component of V is incremented by the weight of that feature;
> if the i-th bit of the hash value is 0, the i-th component
> of V is decremented by the weight of that feature. When
> all features have been processed, some components of V are
> positive while others are negative. The signs of components
> determine the corresponding bits of the final fingerprint.

However, in your case, you might found other similarity functions like cosine distance or euclidean distance perform better. Try to find the best similarity function for your problem if `simhash` does not work well for you.

## Query for similar documents

After you generate the fingerprint for each document, similar documents should have similar fingerprints (similar means their fingerprints' hamming distance is small). For more details, please refer to  [near duplicate web page detection](http://www.wwwconference.org/www2007/papers/paper215.pdf).

## Edit

If you cannot do the first step, i.e., decoding, simply counting the occurrences of each unique integer is still doable. You can apply tf-idf to those unique integers and follow the subsequent steps.

Answer (score 1):

hmm interesting question. The answer AFAIK is simply **NO**

*text documents* means words e.i. synonyms, collocation, suffixes, prefixes (stemming)...

*big integer byte array*  lacks a possibility to cover all those things. Therefore comparing files transformed into byte arrays won't tell you whether there are similar texts.

Take this answer as a answer to your caption. Body of your question is rather complicated and it seems you are mixing more things together (it is hard to understand) - maybe making more simple questions would help ...

Comment: maybe the body can be rephrased as: Are there other techniques to transform a text into a byte array consisting of integers values that can be helpful into detecting similarities other than applied a word frequency operation on the text?

Comment: yep - much clearer! Most likely, there are some but I'd suppose all of them are sharing basic idea of tf-idf (as far as I know) ...

Comment: Can you cite some of them? If there are some an they share the tf-idf idea then there is no luck with integer byte vectors

Comment: hmm, i haven't been working with anything else than tf-idf, so I can't help. Anyway, look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf there are some other techniques, however, they look like improved version of tf-idf. I'd stay stick to tf-idf - but it depends on what is your ultimate goal...

Answer (score 1):

Bloom filter fits your case if you don't mind the TF-IDF approach: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/navendu/mypapers/webdb-167.pdf
This way you can make vector arbitrary small or large depending on your tolerance to false positives.

Anyway looking at the NLP toolkit most of the algorithms can be adapted for the task, question is how do you specify similarity?

If you can specify different classes of documents then it's worth looking into Naive Bayes or if you want to define similarity differently MaxEnt model might work for you:
http://www.kamalnigam.com/papers/maxent-ijcaiws99.pdf

Comment: Does anything forbids me by using the technique of the bloom filter paper for feature extraction (content-defined-chunks technique) as a vector representation of the file and then apply the cosine similarity technique?

Comment: I think this discussion might answer your question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/the-probability-by-which-bloom-filters-preserves-the-order-relation-given-a-simi